# Requerying subform only work sometimes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to requery a subform which diplays customer details.

I am sure my sql works as the subform works fine when not influenced by the main form.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT tblCustomer.[Job ID], tblCustomer.[Customer Name], tblCustomer.[Street Name], tblCustomer.Area, tblAppointments.[Appointment Date] " _
    & "FROM tblCustomer " _
    & "LEFT JOIN tblAppointments ON tblCustomer.[Job ID] = tblAppointments.[Job Number].Value " _
    & "WHERE [Customer Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*'" _
    & "OR [Job ID] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*'" _
    & "OR [Street Name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*'" _
    & "OR [Area] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*'" _
    & "OR [Appointment Date] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*'" _
    & "ORDER BY tblAppointments.[Appointment Date];"

    Me.subCustomerList.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.subCustomerList.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

The debugger shows an error at the following line:

```
Me.subCustomerList.Form.RecordSource = sql
```

I also get the error message

> object or class does not support set of events

Comment: Your `OR` and `ORDER` clauses need space between each other

Comment: use `Debug.Print sql` to display your completed query in the immediate window, and then paste it into Access to see if you get an error there as well.

Comment: Your original recordsource is possibly fine but not when you run attempt to change it.

Comment: I printed sql and got the following
SELECT tblCustomer.[Job ID], tblCustomer.[Customer Name], tblCustomer.[Street Name], tblCustomer.Area, tblAppointments.[Appointment Date]  FROM tblCustomer  LEFT JOIN tblAppointments ON tblCustomer.[Job ID] = tblAppointments.[Job Number].Value  WHERE [Customer Name] LIKE '*s*' OR [Job ID] LIKE '*s*' OR [Street Name] LIKE '*s*' OR [Area] LIKE '*s*' OR [Appointment Date] LIKE '*s*' ORDER BY tblAppointments.[Appointment Date];

Comment: Parfait - i'm not sure I know what you mean in your second comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why does your printed query not have asterisks and where is the spaces before `OR`? Please be sure exact query is being posted here.

Comment: Yes I noticed that but there is asterisks in the immediate window. I think it may be as I am pasting it into this comments section.

Comment: Include it in your question instead of in the comments. And does it run when you paste it into an Access query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider parameterization with a stored query for several reasons in your case:

1. Helps avoid syntax issues like what you may have since Access will not allow you to save a query with syntax errors if using the GUI query designer;
2. Better maintainability than a concatenated SQL string which requires single/double quote enclosure and you abstract data from code;
3. The Access engine compiles stored queries to best execution plan so will be more efficient than a VBA called SQL string (i.e., use index on `JOIN`).

**SQL** *(save as a query object with parameter to be referenced by name in VBA)*

```sql
PARAMETERS txtKeywordsParam TEXT(255);
SELECT c.[Job ID], c.[Customer Name], c.[Street Name], c.Area, a.[Appointment Date]
FROM tblCustomer c
LEFT JOIN tblAppointments a ON c.[Job ID] = a.[Job Number]
WHERE c.[Customer Name] LIKE txtKeywordsParam 
  OR c.[Job ID] LIKE txtKeywordsParam 
  OR c.[Street Name] LIKE txtKeywordsParam 
  OR c.[Area] LIKE txtKeywordsParam 
  OR a.[Appointment Date] LIKE txtKeywordsParam 
ORDER BY a.[Appointment Date];
```

**VBA**

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Dim qdef As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset

    ' OPEN QUERY AND BIND PARAM
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedParamQuery")
    qdef!txtKeywordsParam = "*" & Me.txtKeyword & "*"

    ' ASSIGN QUERY RESULT TO RECORDSET
    Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()    

    ' APPLY RECORDSET TO FORM 
    Set Me.subCustomerList.Form.Recordset = rst    
    Set qdef = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. I'm still quite green so learning this will be on my goal list. I have fixed it for now and am a little wary about changing it especially with code that I would be guessing with. Thank you for your help though I will study parameterization and use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new subform and copied the one that did not work and everything seems to be running well.